# Error using promises in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, promise, ethereum

Even though this is related to Ethereum, it's actually a JavaScript question.

My goal is to have a function to deploy an Ethereum contract which returns its address once the contract is deployed (sidenote: I'm not interested in deploying it with Mist or other options).

```
function deploy(contractName, accountOwner, _gas) {
    // Get the contract code from contracts
    const input = fs.readFileSync('contracts/' + contractName + '.sol').toString();
    const output = solc.compile(input);
    // The trailing ':' is needed otherwise it crashes
    const bytecode = output.contracts[':' + contractName].bytecode;
    const abi = JSON.parse(output.contracts[':' + contractName].interface);
    const contract = web3.eth.contract(abi);
    const contractInstance = contract.new({
        data: '0x' + bytecode,
        from: accountOwner,
        gas: _gas
    }, sendContract(err, res));
    contractInstance.then(console.log(contractInstance), console.log("Failure"));
}

function sendContract(err, res) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return reject(err);
        } else {
            console.log("Transaction Hash: " + res.transactionHash);
            // If we have an address property, the contract was deployed
            if (res.address) {
                console.log('Contract address: ' + res.address);
            resolve(res);
            }
        }
    })
}
```

This isn't working because it returns `ReferenceError: err is not defined`. I know it's related to the promise but I am not sure how to fix it, even though I have tried different things. Could someone please point me to the error?

I know there are many questions like this here but I (1) have read them as well as promises explanations ([this one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and [this one](https://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript-promises-for-dummies), among others) and (2) am really stuck and would really appreciate some help.

Comment: well, you are passing the result of calling `sendContract(err, res)` as the second argument to `contract.new` ... perhaps that was simply meant to be `sendContract` without the `(err, res)`?

Comment: Same problem with the `console.log`s.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22539815/arent-promises-just-callbacks

Comment: The OP is trying to promisify `contract.new()`, and the `sendContract(err, res)` issue is only one aspect of the required fix. I have voted to reopen.

Answer (score 0):

> This isn't working because it returns ReferenceError: err is not defined.

You define `err` as an argument to this function:

> ```
> function sendContract(err, res)
> ```

As with all arguments, it is a **locally scoped** variable to that function.

You attempt to use that variable here:

> ```
>  }, sendContract(err, res));
> ```

So you attempt to *call* `sendContract` passing a variable named `err` *from outside the function* into the local variable of the same name inside that function.

Since you haven't defined `err` outside the function, you get a reference error.

You have the same problem with `res` but you don't see it because the `err` version triggers first.

---

> I know it's related to the promise

It isn't.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So should I replace `sendContract(err, res)` by `sendContract` only? I've tried that but then I got an error `TypeError: contractInstance.then is not a function`. If not, could you please show me what change would be required for it to work?

Comment: It looks like passing a promise into `contract.new` doesn't make it return a promise.

Comment: Probably you should [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises).